# IAM authentication with SoftLayer API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ibm-iam

I'm using the SoftLayer REST API, and instead of username and API key, I'd like to authenticate with my IAM token. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually now possible.  You can use your IAM api key to authenticate with the Softlayer API now.  To do that you can do the following.

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account?objectMask=networkVlanSpan' \
--header 'Authorization: bearer <your token>'
```

To get the token run `ibmcloud iam oauth-tokens`.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually now possible.  You can use your IAM api key to authenticate with the Softlayer API now.  To do that you can do the following.

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account?objectMask=networkVlanSpan' \
--header 'Authorization: bearer <your token>'
```

To get the token run `ibmcloud iam oauth-tokens`.